# Multi-cursor editing in Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, xcode10, multicursorediting

What is 'Multi-cursor editing' in Xcode 10 editor. (more information about the same is mentioned in [release notes](https://download.developer.apple.com/Documentation/Xcode_10_beta_Release_Notes/Xcode_10_Beta_Release_Notes.pdf) but unable to understand.)

How exactly does it work?

Comment: its used for allowing to quickly edit multiple ranges of code at once

Comment: Good question actually. I found [this twitter post](https://twitter.com/dmartincy/status/988094014804160514) on this matter that seems to talk about some third party plug-in / workaround. I'm not sure how to enter that editing mode, however.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/102/?time=2518 for a quick demo

Answer (score 215, accepted):

> To edit multiple instances of text within different sections of a document, you can use multi-cursor editing. This allows multiple cursors to be placed in different spots so text **can be added, modified, or deleted**.

its the name of **Source Editor**, for reference purpose I taken the answer from [whats-new-in-xcode10](https://developerinsider.co/whats-new-in-xcode-10/) and [Sample link 1](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html) and [Sample link 2](https://qiita.com/okuderap/items/3289265e4645a29b6808)

> The Xcode 10 Source Editor now supports multi-cursor editing allowing you to quickly edit multiple ranges of code at once.

- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + click
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>
- <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>
- <kbd>option</kbd> + drag

> With a source control-enabled project the source editor displays changes made by a developer in the gutter and shows changes made by other developers that haven’t yet been pulled into the project

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the up arrow, and pretty much what every other symbol means except the command key? my retina macbook does not show those symbols, for example the option key just says "option".

Comment: @MarcusJ - I modified the answer, its easy to understand, for sample you get [here](https://qiita.com/okuderap/items/3289265e4645a29b6808)

Comment: Is it possible to change the key binding for this ? I'd rather not use the control key.

Comment: I wish they would have just done command + click like Sublime.

Comment: I was hoping to see something like Sublime or Atom's `Cmd + D` multi-select/multi-cursor. I don't know why Xcode has to be so spare with helpful features.

Comment: @Dan just change the keyboard shortcut for "Select Next Occurrence" to `Cmd + D` in preferences :)

Comment: To select Multiple lines simply use "Shift + Ctrl + Drag" in Xcode10, which could achieve by "Cmd + Drag" earlier ✌️✌️✌️✌️

Comment: I searched all key bindings for "multi", "caret", "cursor", "input", "add" but never found this feature. Finally resorted to DDG, and then to Google. Great discoverability.

Comment: For me multiline drag is done with `Ctrl` + `Option`

Comment: @Dan, Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545206/865175).

Answer (score 36):

The best way to use it is by using the `Select Next Occurrence` command from the `Find` menu.

Its default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>, but you could set it to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to mimic Sublime Text's behavior.

This way, you can edit code lines that are different, whereas the solutions in the other answers only allow you to edit similar lines.

For example, if you have this code:

```c
NSString *myStringg = @"stringg";
// print the stringg
NSLog(@"Here is my stringg: %@", myStringg);
```

you simply:

1. manually select the first `Stringg` occurrence from the first line using the cursor
2. hit the `Select Next Occurrence`'s keyboard shortcut 4 times
3. hit the <kbd>right</kbd> arrow key
4. hit <kbd>backspace</kbd>

and you'll have:

```c
NSString *myString = @"string";
// print the string
NSLog(@"Here is my string: %@", myString);
```

Answer (score 14):

#### Usages

(1) Edit CodingKey

using <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + drag

[image: demo-1]

(2) Edit method parameter indentation

using <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> + click

[image: demo-2]

#### Related Defaults

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode PegasusMultipleCursorsEnabled -bool true
```

### Reference

1. https://sarunw.com/posts/multi-cursor-editing-in-xcode/
2. https://github.com/ctreffs/xcode-defaults
3. Mac keyboard shortcuts
   https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> 
when you wish to edit same text in file for multiple times
e.g

```
    option_A.isEnabled = false
    option_B.isEnabled = false
    option_C.isEnabled = false
    option_D.isEnabled = false
```

in this i have to put true on all four lines then it should be better for to put true at once by using **<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>** rather than edit each line

Answer (score 3):

There is also a keyboard shortcut available for those like me who use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Sublime.

It's called `Selection - Split Selection By Lines`. I set it to <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> but I had to set the `Show Library` shortcut to something else random that I don't use to resolve the conflict.

Comment: For me `Select All Find Matches` instead of `Selection - Split Selection By Lines` worked.